# Extern Enum Function Not Working—"Undefined Reference To" Error

Tags: c++, enums, arduino, extern, platformio

I have the following files:

**KeywordParser.h**

```cpp
#include <Ramp.h>

#ifndef KeywordParser_h
#define KeywordParser_h

extern enum ramp_mode parseRampMode(char* command);
extern enum loop_mode parseLoopMode(char* command);

#endif
```

**KeywordParser.cpp**

```cpp
#include <KeywordParser.h>
#include <Ramp.h>

enum ramp_mode parseRampMode(const char* command) {
  if (strcmp(command, "NONE") == 0) return NONE;
  if (strcmp(command, "LINEAR") == 0) return LINEAR;
// ...

  return NONE;
};

enum loop_mode parseLoopMode(const char* command) {
  if (strcmp(command, "ONCEFORWARD") == 0) return ONCEFORWARD;
  if (strcmp(command, "LOOPFORWARD") == 0) return LOOPFORWARD;
// ...

  return ONCEFORWARD;
};
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <KeywordParser.h>
// a bunch of code, eventually, though, I call the functions

void loop() {
  parseRampMode("NONE");
  parseLoopMode("ONCEFORWARD");
}
```

I am using [PlatformIO](https://platformio.org/) to do the compilation. I am including many other header files that work just fine (albeit they aren't for `extern enum` functions; they're for classes).

Now, though, I get this error for each time I use the functions:

> <artificial>: undefined reference to `parseLoopMode(char*)'

> <artificial>: undefined reference to `parseRampMode(char*)'

My IntelliSense gives no indication of wrongdoing. Any idea what the problem here is? This is unimaginably frustrating. I have a hint that it has something to do with needing `extern "C"`, but I've tried that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, thank you [Ken White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62576/ken-white)! I looked through the link you showed and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574403/12944748).

The new **KeywordParser.h**

```cpp
#include <Ramp.h>

#ifndef KeywordParser_h
#define KeywordParser_h

extern enum ramp_mode parseRampMode(const char* command);
extern enum loop_mode parseLoopMode(const char* command);

#endif
```

(Look at the parameters.)